# List objects doesn't show using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I am not sure what i am doing wrong but my objects doesn't want to display in my partial view with angular's ng-repeat

**SCRIPT**

```
$scope.ExecutivePayList = [];
$scope.LoadExecutivesPay = function () {
    $.get(loadExecutivesPayUrl, function (data) {
        if (data.IsSuccess) {
            //Load data
            $scope.ExecutivePayList.length = 0;
            //$scope.ExecutivePayList = angular.fromJson(data.Results);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                $scope.ExecutivePayList.push(data.Results[i])
            }
            console.log($scope.ExecutivePayList);
        }
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="executive in ExecutivePayList">
    <td class="">
        {{executive.NameOfIncumbent}}
    </td>
    <td class="">
        {{executive.Position}}
    </td>
    <td class="">
        {{executive.PatersonGrade}}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        {{executive.NumMonthsInPosition}}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">


    </td>
</tr>
```

JSON Output

```
{SectionID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", Results: Array(2), Message: null, IsSuccess: true, DetailedMessage: null}
Results: Array(2)
0:{SectionID: "b8e6466e-44b8-4a47-bdc6-a84e07200780", NameOfIncumbent: "Daily M", Position: "CEO", PatersonGrade: "", NumMonthsInPosition: 12}
1:{SectionID: "2290a579-7f86-437f-a806-36049eeb7c8b", NameOfIncumbent: "Field RH", Position: "CEO", PatersonGrade: "", NumMonthsInPosition: 12}
```

Not sure if this might be useful but i call my method on ng-init

```
<div ng-controller="ExecutivePayController" ng-init="LoadExecutivesPay()">
```

Comment: why are you not using `$http.get()`?

Comment: I implemented it right now. Force of habit in using $.get(). That still doesn't solve my issue

Comment: can you show the output here?

Comment: Can you show your output JSON

Comment: @VinodKumarKashyap see edit

Comment: What's the out put of this `console.log($scope.ExecutivePayList);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly since you don't use angular's way to make the AJAX call you need to call `angular.fromJson(data.Results)`. Furthermore since this is an asynchronous operation you have to manually trigger a digest cycle. So you have to call `$scope.$apply()` right after you update your `$scope.ExecutivePayList`.

Final code:

```
$scope.ExecutivePayList = [];
$scope.LoadExecutivesPay = function () {
    $.get(loadExecutivesPayUrl, function (data) {
        if (data.IsSuccess) {
            //Load data
            $scope.ExecutivePayList.length = 0;
            $scope.ExecutivePayList = angular.fromJson(data.Results);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                $scope.ExecutivePayList.push(data.Results[i])
            }
            console.log($scope.ExecutivePayList);
            $scope.$apply(); // Here you trigger the digest cycle.
        }
    });
};
```

**Update on how to do this in angular way.**

It is recommended to have your http calls in a `service` instead of performing them in your controller as you do now. In any case you have to have the `$http` injected in your service or controller (current case).
Then your controller function should look like this:

```
$scope.LoadExectivesPayUrl = function() {
   $http.get(loadExecutivesPayUrl).then((data) => {
      if(data.IsSuccess) {
            //Load data
            $scope.ExecutivePayList.length = 0;

            //No need to parse json because angular has done this automatically 
            //for you

            for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                $scope.ExecutivePayList.push(data.Results[i])
            }
            console.log($scope.ExecutivePayList);
            // No need to $scope.$apply() , since digest cycle is performed 
            // within $http operation
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are checking for `if (data.IsSuccess) {` and your output does not have it.

Secondly you are using the `data.Results.length;`. Also here Results is not there.

Comment: try making `if (data.IsSuccess) {` this to `if (data.IsSuccess === true) {`

Comment: That section works fine. When I call this $scope.ExecutivePayList = angular.fromJson(data.Results); it shows that $scope.ExecutivePayList  has data but when i do the repeat it doesn't show the data